# Why is rangeOfString returning a value instead of NSNotFound?

Tags: swift

[image: Debug Image]

In the screenshot above you can see that `rangeOfString` has returned a location for "DEnt" in the string "Why was #ThisIsACoup trending? - BBC News"

I would expect it to have returned `NSNotFound` instead since "DEnt" is not a substring of the string in the `tmp` variable.  Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Here's the code used in the screenshot.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = xmlParser.arrParsedData.filter({ (dict) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = dict["title"]!
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0) {
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows range.location = a huge number.  That huge number is NSNotFound (on 64-bit platforms); it's doing the right thing.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I was just dividing 9223372036854775807 (+1) by 1024 to see if it was just a big 64-bit number and it turns out it is.  So I need to check for NSNotFound as well as >= 9223372036854775807?

Comment: No, just checking NSNotFound should be fine.  Your code looks good to me already. Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: Yes the problem I had was elsewhere and the 9223372036854775807 value was fine, thanks